# angular 2 how to assign an array of JSON response using Observable and map in typescript interface and retrieve in html using *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

```
export interface Relation{
name: string;
address: string;
dob: number;
}
```

My JSON response is

```
[ {"name":"John", "address":"xyz", "dob":"2000-01-10"},
{"name":"Jamie", "address":"abc", "dob":"1990-01-10"}
]
```

This is not mapping the response to the Interface! That;s the problem.

```
relations:Relation []=[];
getRelations() : Observable<Relation[]> {
   return this.http.get('url for json response').map(this.extractData).do(data=>console.log("Get all responses"+JSON.stringify(data))).catch(error => this.errorMessage = error);
}

extractData( response : Response){
let body = response.json();
console.log("Body", body);
return body.data;
}
```

i call the get Relations but get nothing !

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.getRelations().subscribe(relations=> relations, error=> this.errorMessage=<any>error);
}
```

When i try to retrieve the data in HTML as a table row i get nothing! Which means either the Relation[] array is not initialized itself or i'm missing something here.

when i do this i get nothing !

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of relations"> 
<td> row.name</td>
<td> row.address</td>
<td> row.dob</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where are you assigning `relations` to your response from `getRelations()`? Edit: Nevermind, I see you just added it.

Comment: @BenBeck When i do this.getRelations().subscribe(relations=> relations, error=> this.errorMessage=<any>error); won't it automatically assign it to relations?

Comment: Try using `.subscribe(relations => this.relations = relations)`

Comment: @BenBeck Still not working :( Is it because of my getRelations() : Observable<Relation[]> {
   return this.http.get('url for json response').map(this.extractData).do(data=>console.log("Get all responses"+JSON.stringify(data))).catch(error => this.errorMessage = error);
}

Comment: I strongly feel the .map function is not mapping ! how can i even verify that it's been mapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your response does not contain an object `data`, but is just an array, so you should change your `extractData` to return either the response as is, (and alternatively an empty array):

```ts
extractData( response : Response){
  let body = response.json();
  console.log("Body", body);
  return body || []; // here!
}
```

Also you need to actually assign the data to a variable in your component:

```ts
this.getRelations()
  .subscribe(relations=> {
     this.relations = relations
  });
```

And in your template you are not actually displaying the objects and their properties since you are not using interpolation `{{ }}`, so need to add that:

```ts
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of relations"> 
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    <td>{{row.address}}</td>
    <td> {{row.dob}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also it seems you are handling all in the component, we usually have a service to handle the http calls and mapping, and just subscribe in the component.

**Service:**

```ts
@Injectable()
export class Service {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getRelations() : Observable<Relation[]> {
    return this.http.get('url')
     .map(this.extractData)
     .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  extractData( response : Response){
    let body = response.json();
    console.log("Body", body);
    return body || [];
  }

}
```

and in **component**:

```ts
constructor(private service: Service){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.service.getRelations().subscribe(relations=> {
    this.relations = relations;
  });
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nw1KomPL0xM1gSyG3sCl?p=preview)**

Comment: where exactly does this data *disappear*? Are you getting a response at all?

Comment: I updated my answer and with a plunker. there was nothing wrong before (besides the html part) but I wanted to show that we usually use a service for our http calls. And I added a demo. Compare your code to that.

Comment: Yeah i get the body from extract Data, but after that i have no idea whether it's mapped or not! because when i try to use it in html it is not there!     console.log("Body", body);
the above part gives response

Comment: I even used [(ngModel)] = relations in html but still i couldn't get it :(

Comment: your example works but i do the same it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/hPALhr2pX8Ux35QM7Smj/ i have updated my code to the plunkr will you please let me know what I'm doing wrong ? or this link http://plnkr.co/edit/hPALhr2pX8Ux35QM7Smj?p=info

Comment: Well, looking quickly at your plunker, you have forgotten to change the `extractData` it should return `body`, not `body.data` :)

Comment: Wait... I have to take a closer look at your plunker and see if I can find any other error.  ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm losing sleep over this :( In your example everything works ! even my data as response,However, i do the same in my local it fails!

Comment: It seems to work fine when I removed `data` from `body.data` and removed the `[(ngModel)]="relations"` from your template. Now, if you have different property names in your objects response and interface you need to explicitly map those properties, so since there is no matching propertyname `relationName`, it's not showing in template, onlu `visible` and `instancenumber` You need to tell Angular which property belongs with which... http://plnkr.co/edit/gb9L2BPaco6aER8pHp17?p=preview

Comment: Wow , you're awesome ! it works yeah got the error in my code there was a mismatch of response too :D I wish i would give your answer a 100 thumbs up ! Again Thanks a lot for helping me out when i felt helpless :)

Comment: also i want to understand why ngModel doesn't bind to relations?

Comment: haha :D Really glad to hear it worked! :) :) As for your question `ngModel` doesn't work with arrays, only with primitive types and objects. Have a nice weekend and happy coding!

Comment: I have one more issue after this, i want to modify if the user clicks on modify the data, now i have to redirect it to the add form which is present in another component. How can i make the redirection happen?and how can i update that form?

Comment: should i post it as a new question, anyhow i'm confident that you will solve it easily :D

Comment: Yeah, I'd be happy to help, but I think that is a completely different question, and you need to provide different code for that question, i.e the click event, the component code for the form etc. In theory I can tell what I suggest....**1**. you should store that clicked item in a service **2**. then navigate to the other component, **3**. fetch that item from service after navigation, which you then populate the form with. That is what you should do in **theory** but if you need assistance with the code this belongs to a new question :)

Comment: Sure i will frame the question and post it in few minutes. :D Thanks again ! Will see you in the next question ;)

Comment: Haha. To point another usual scenario is to pass id (or something unique) as a route parameter and then when in other component make a http call to fetch the item and then populate the form. It really depends on your backend of course and you have the possibility to do this. I also strongly suggest you try either of this approaches and if you encounter problems, *then* ask the question ;)

Comment: i tried using routerLink to redirect to the page but i'm not able to translate the row data to form fields! need your help. I have posted a new question for the same, not sure whether i was able to explain myself clearly or not ! plnkr.co/edit/x36vXy5M2Vu6bj0Xh0oG?p=preview this is the link for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your interface to:

```
export interface Relation{
name: string;
address: string;
dob: string;
}
```

dob is a `string` type, not a `number`.

Further, as Ben said, you either are not assigning your response to `relations`, or simply did not include that part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code above shows incorrect syntax for ngFor . Look at the documentation for more details

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: It was a typo i have used of instead of for inside *ngFor

Comment: Yep , then the HTML template as well .
And you are missing   .subscribe(relations=> this.relations )

Comment: i have added it .subscribe(relations => this.relations = realtions) but still not working.

Comment: In this case could you please provide a plunkr ? That should speed up things

Comment: Yeah i haven't used plunkr before so please give me couple of minutes to come back with the response! Also thank you very much for helping I'm kind of lost here :(

Comment: Can i ping you privately ? as the data is sensitive?